# one user viewing another users profile in django

Tags: python, html, django, model

I would like to implement a functionality where another user A clicks the picture of a different user B and is automatically redirected to the profile of user B. how do I do this? please look at my HTML where I stated something about a link

view.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} profile'
```

html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="icl-NavigationList-item">
   <div class="icl-NavigationList-link icl-NavigationList--primary">
   <div class="icl-NavigationList-text">
   <h2 class="icl-NavigationList-title">
     <div class="upperText">
      <h2 class="card-title"style="background-color:{{post.post_colours}};">{{post.job_title}}</h2>
    <a class="a-tags" href="*{{ i need to link the post author's profile  here}}*" data-tippy-content="@dribble_handle">
  <img  src="{{post.author.profile.profile_pic.url}}" style="border-radius: 100%;float:right;" 
  alt="author"width="30" height="30"></a></div>
  <div class="lowerText"> <p class="card-text">{{post.currency}} {{post.salary}}</p>
   <p class="card-text"> Posted on {{post.date_posted}} by {{post.author}} </p>
  <br>
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

my model

```
class profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
  category = models.CharField(max_length= 1000, choices = 
  Select_category,default='other')



def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.kwargs['username']
    user_profile = profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    gigs = Gig.objects.filter(user__username=username, status=True)
    print(user_profile.values())
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'user_profile': user_profile, 'gigs': gigs,'name': username})
```

Comment: And your question is....? So far, you've given code and said what you want, but you haven't explained what's wrong with the output of that code

Comment: how can i go about it?

Comment: Go about _what_? Like I edited my comment - you have some statement about what you want and a bunch of code. If you're just asking how to implement something, then the code would be a useless distraction and I'd vote to close it as needing more detail. _As is happens_, your code looks reasonable, but I still don't know what you're struggling with

Comment: i would like toknow how to make one user view another users profile sir.. i have no idea how to make that happen

Comment: No. Absolutely not. You can explain it with an [edit] to your question. I'm not a personal helpdesk

Comment: okay @roganjosh i've reviewed the question

Comment: If you have a url for user profile page, just add it to href of <a> tag in html.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here’s an edited answer. I took a look at your code, and you don’t have the post model on here, so this is just me trying to put some pieces together to try. Ultimately, our goal should be to have the href look like this:

href="{{ post.author.get_absolute_url }}"

Note here that it is NOT {{ post.author.profile.get_absolute_url }}. It probably seems counter-intuitive to leave out profile in the url, but remember that the username argument passed is part of the User model, not the profile model.

**(Note: the url will definitely depend on what the model for your post looks like. If the author is a ForeignKey to the user model, use what I’m typing here. If it is a ForeignKey relating to the profile model, you would replace author with author.user)**

If that doesn’t work, make sure your urls.py is set up correctly.

**urls.py**

```
...
path(‘URL_YOU_WANT/<username>/, views.VIEW_NAME, name=“NAME”),
...
```

**(Note: keep “<username>” exactly like that. It’s how Django knows to expect the username argument passed by your href.)**

If things still aren’t working, I would rewrite your views.py view to be clearer. There is a bit of redundancy and confusion with your views.py and models.py. Here’s how I would go about it:

**models.py**

```
class profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
     bio = models.TextField(blank = True)

     def __str__(self):
           return f’{self.user.username} profile’
```

**views.py**

```
def user_profile(request, username):
     user = User.objects.get(username = username)
     user_profile = profile.objects.get(user = user)
     gigs = Gig.objects.filter(user = user, status = True)
     return render(request, ‘blog/profile.html’, {‘user_profile’: user_profile, ‘gigs’: gigs, ‘name’: username})
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: yes i tried it..yet im still not able to route to another users profile..i think im still doing something wrong